# calling a callback in library

Tags: ios, iphone, callback

i am using reachability class where in i have to call method in it called "startNotifier" which in turn calls  a callback function.I am using creating a lib which contains reachability.h/.m and two other files with following code:

wifi.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Reachability.h"

@protocol MyDelegate
-(void)currentInternetStatus:(BOOL)isInternetAvailable;
@end

@interface wifi : NSObject
{
    Reachability *internetReachable;
    Reachability *hostReachable;
    id <MyDelegate>delegate ;
}
#pragma mark Booleans
@property BOOL hostActive;
@property BOOL internetActive;
@property (nonatomic,retain)id <MyDelegate>delegate ;

#pragma mark Functions
-(void)internetAvailability;

@end
```

wifi.m

```
#import "wifi.h"

@implementation wifi

@synthesize hostActive,internetActive,delegate;

#pragma mark Methods for checking Network Connection

/** Method for checking Network Connection*/
-(void)internetAvailability
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
internetReachable = [[Reachability alloc]init];
//Reachability *internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
[internetReachable startNotifier];
}


/** Notification called to check networks presence*/
- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)

    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");

            self.internetActive = NO;
            [self.delegate currentInternetStatus:NO];
            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            self.internetActive = YES;
            [self.delegate currentInternetStatus:NO];
            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            self.internetActive = YES;
            [self.delegate currentInternetStatus:NO];
            break;

        }
    }

    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus)

    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            self.hostActive = NO;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
            self.hostActive = YES;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
            self.hostActive = YES;

            break;

        }
    }

}
@end
```

when i write the same code in appdelegate it works ,but when i write the same (.h/.m)
in library it doesn't.

This is how I'm using it:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    wifi *obj = [[wifi alloc]init];
    obj.delegate = self;
    [obj internetAvailability];

    return YES;
}

- (void)currentInternetStatus:(BOOL)isInternetAvailable
{
    NSLog(@"net status %d", isInternetAvailable);
}
```

Comment: Describe how it isn't working. Show how you're using the `wifi` class. Why are you retaining the delegate?

Comment: i have added code above.

Comment: So, how is it not working? Does it compile? If yes I guess it runs, so the problem is you are not receiving the callback in your `currentInternetStatus:`, is that it?

Comment: yes it runs .but i dont receive any thing in callback

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your `wifi *obj = [[wifi alloc]init];`, but never retaining it. So, after the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` finishes, the instance gets destroyed.

Because the process of checking the network availability is asynchronous the notification is never sent.

You need to retain the `obj` instance. For example, by storing it in a 'strong' property in your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: sorry it is working. i missed something else. Thanks a lot u have saved me :)